# REGEX not working- Filter the Splunk results

Tags: java, regex, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I have Splunk results in following format:

```
2021-11-13 01:02:50.127 ERROR 23 --- [ taskExecutor-2] c.c.p.r.service.RedisService             : The Redis Cache had no record for key: null Returning empty list.

2021-10-22 21:11:51.996 ERROR 22 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.c.p.r.service.SftpService           : Could not delete file: /-/XYZ.FILE - 4: Failure

2021-10-22 02:05:14.426 ERROR 22 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.c.p.r.service.SftpService           : Could not delete file: /-/XYZ.FILE - 4: Failure
```

I want to create a Visualization in the following format:

| Error Message | Time | Error code | TaskExecutor Number | Service name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Redis Cache had no record for key: null Returning empty list. | 2021-11-13 01:02:50.127 | 23 | taskExecutor-2 | c.c.p.r.service.RedisService | 1 |
| Could not delete file: /-/XYZ.FILE - 4: Failure | 2021-10-22 21:11:51.996 | 22 | taskExecutor-1 | c.c.p.r.service. SftpService | 2 |
| Could not delete file: /-/XYZ.FILE - 4: Failure | 2021-10-22 02:05:14.426 | 22 | taskExecutor-1 | c.c.p.r.service. SftpService | 2 |

The **count variable** is based on the "Error Message" only. Since "Could not delete file: /-/XYZ.FILE - 4: Failure" appeared twice, hence the count is set to 2. As the logs grow, and this message occurrence increase, this count should increase too.

I tried using erex and substring from Splunk but kinda failed miserably!

Here is the query I tried:

```
index=my_index "ERROR * ---" "taskExecutor-*" | rex "^(?<Time>\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+\s+(?<Error_Code>\d+)[^\]]+\]\s+(?<Service_Name>\S+)\:\s+(?<Error_Message>.+)"
| table Error_Message Time Error_Code Service_Name 
| eventstats count as Count by Error_Message Error_Code Service_Name
```

Seems like there is a problem with the REGEX: https://regex101.com/r/smWKM8/2

Any help on how to fix this REGEX would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The regex is just missing some white space.

```
(?<Time>\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+\s+(?<Error_Code>\d+)[^\]]+\]\s+(?<Service_Name>\S+)\s*:\s+(?<Error_Message>.+)
```

Based on the statement `count variable is based on the "Error Message" only`, I tweaked the query a little.

```
index=my_index "ERROR * ---" "taskExecutor-*" 
| rex "^(?<Time>\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+\s+(?<Error_Code>\d+)[^\]]+\]\s+(?<Service_Name>\S+)\s*:\s+(?<Error_Message>.+)"
| eventstats count as Count by Error_Message 
| table Error_Message Time Error_Code Service_Name
```